# sorl-thumbnail adds a background color when padding is used

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using `sorl-thumbnail` and it works as expected except for when I use `padding` (which I have to) a white background is added.

I know I can change that color, but I want no color (i.e transparency).

Is there any hack or another library to fix this?